# Using mutually communicative properties in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, function, properties

I don't know if the title truly describes what I am trying to achieve, so please feel free to edit this to a more suiting/appropriate title so that it gets the point across.

I have a situation where I need to be able to retrieve a string representation of a numeric value, and vice versa - get a numeric representation of a string value.

I have two shared functions in a helper class, as follows:

```
Shared Function GetStringRepresentation(value as Integer) as String
   Select Case value
     Case 1
        Return "One"
     Case 2
        Return "Two"
   End Select
End Function

Shared Function GetNumericRepresentation(value as String) as Integer
   Select Case value
     Case "One"
        Return 1
     Case "Two"
        Return 2
   End Select
End Function
```

Now, in a separate class I have the following properties:

```
Private _stringRep As String
Public Property StringRep As String
    Get
        Return _stringRep
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _intRep = HelperClass.GetNumericRepresentation(value)
    End Set
End Property


Private _numericRep As Integer
Private Property NumericRep As Integer
    Get
        Return _numericRep
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _stringRep = HelperClass.GetStringRepresentation(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

At the moment this is security through obscurity. Please be aware I am avoiding using enumerations for the fact that I can't have multiple-word enumerations (i.e `"THIS IS NUMBER ONE", "THIS IS NUMBER TWO"`).

Any suggestions as to how I can go about this whilst following the DRY principles? I am leaving enumerations to the very last option, the option preceding enum's is SQL data queries (as the information is coming from an SQL database); but I want to try avoid this completely.

**EDIT** - I'm adding this in due to two comments regarding using code tables in the database, and the second being that there is no security at all present.

Please understand, I have this information in code tables in the database, and these are pulled into a local memory cache on the applications launch, if any new values have been added. I pass through either the string value or the integer value, and put in the return type I want, and it will return the aforementioned return. However, I am asking if there is a way to do this at launch to put it into the application directly and still have some level of security from decompilers, as compared to writing the data to a local memory cache.
Also, the examples I have put in are completely unrelated to my current code - the structure is similar to a single object, but the code is cross-communicative between 6-7 objects, and then goes through business layers and data-access layers, before being passed to/retrieved from the database - which ties a single table through to many reference tables (thus, my aforementioned comment about security through obscurity).

I hope this clarifies what I am after.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why not just call the HelperClass methods directly or use an extension method?

Comment: why not make the expanded information part of a domain entity/code table in the database

Comment: "security through obscurity" ?! There are no security in your example.

Comment: @the_lotus Please view the edit. Maybe this will clarify the 'security' side of the comment; aswell as what I am looking for - I'm looking for advice on how to do something, not the code :) Thanks for the answer though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Plutonix We're currently using a database table that is written to the local memory cache, which we then access through the code - I'm just trying to see if we can perhaps drop a few of those tables from memory and have some of the values which will never increase/decrease in size hard-coded into the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would store everything in a dictionary so you don't repeat yourself.

```
Private _numberString As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

_numberString.Add(1, "One")
_numberString.Add(2, "Two")

    Shared Function GetStringRepresentation(ByVal value As Integer) As String
        If _numberString.ContainsKey(value) Then
            Return _numberString(value)
        End If
        Return ""
    End Function

    Shared Function GetNumericRepresentation(ByVal value As String) As Integer
        For Each k As Integer In _numberString.Keys
            If _numberString(k) = value Then
                Return k
            End If
        Next
        Return 0
    End Function
```

Then I would only store one of the value, the integer.

```
    Private _numericRep As Integer

    Public Property StringRep() As String
        Get
            Return Helperclass.GetStringRepresentation(_numericRep)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _numericRep = Helperclass.GetNumericRepresentation(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property NumericRep() As Integer
        Get
            Return _numericRep
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _numericRep = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

To go further, I wouldn't even have a HelperClass but a lookup table that would be cached in the system. Especially if you have multiply type of those lookups. The values in the dictionary could even be stored in a database.

Comment: I've +1 this answer, however I am not looking for the code to this question - I can figure out the coding aspect of it. I'm trying to find the theoretical information behind how to make this work by hard-coding values that will never change into the application, whilst making them as secure as they are currently, the way they are being pulled from the database. Hopefully my comment, and edit will clarify this.